# Ansible login user logged in

Tags: ansible

Can you delegate or Switch to different user that you have logged in, when you execute `ansible-playbook run.yml -k -K` this is prompt of password, but can you switch to user1 to user2 depending of tasks. 
This is different from become_user for escalation, not escalation related.

Comment: If you don't think this question is a duplicate, please clarify exactly what you are trying to do and **why** the other question is not a duplicate. What does "depending of tasks" mean? For now I am voting to leave it closed.

Comment: Switch login for target, in case we have different login that have access to target host. One target is using User1 to connected and Second host using User2 to connect and run subsequent tasks,